# Rails 4 Assets Bug, not loading images

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

To cut a long story short, because I wasted enough time with this stupid framework.
I want to use pure CSS, no SCSS, no css.erb, no mumbo-jumpo that adds more overhead parsing, even if it is 2ms more.

My production.rb file has (I am using webrick):

```
Properties::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both thread web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Enable Rack::Cache to put a simple HTTP cache in front of your application
  # Add `rack-cache` to your Gemfile before enabling this.
  # For large-scale production use, consider using a caching reverse proxy like nginx, varnish or squid.
  # config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files.
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # Set to :debug to see everything in the log.
  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets.
  # application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS in app/assets folder are already added.
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Disable automatic flushing of the log to improve performance.
  # config.autoflush_log = false

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
end
```

Now I have a simple css file under assets/stylesheets called general.css, and it contains this simple line:

```
html{
    background-image:url('homepage_bg_1.jpg');
}
```

Now I have tried:

```
background-image:url('assets/homepage_bg_1.jpg');
background-image:url('public/assets/homepage_bg_1.jpg');
background-image:url('public/homepage_bg_1.jpg');
background-image:url('assets/images/homepage_bg_1.jpg');
```

Nothing works!! It browser still looks for a 'homepage_bg_1.jpg' image which is normal, but in my public assets folder I have 'homepage_bg_1-de4a0800c51d578f152fe5ca821136a6.jpg'.

I am using `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` to precompile my assets.

Now I would assume that Rails is not stupid enough, and will look for that file. But it doesnt. Can somebody just tell me what's wrong with this framework? Should I open an issue in Github? Is the framework trying to make us not use CSS?

Comment: try this `background: image-url("path/to/you/image")`

Comment: If you precompile your assets & serve them statically, you'll not have any overheads at run-time. You might want to look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark

Comment: Nope!! Error in parsing value for 'background'.  Declaration dropped.

Comment: @RichPeck How does that solve my problem?

Comment: I was trying to help you appreciate how Rails works, so you don't blast it so much. I've found the biggest frustrations in programming are "man-made" (I felt my way was best and the system was wrong), when really, all I needed to do was change some of the ways I was doing things

Comment: @TrtTrt sorry, this `sass` you dont use `sass`.

Comment: @RichPeck, Look if that 'fingerprint whatever-thing' is not compatible with pure CSS that has been used for ages, then I don't think I am committing a "man-made" mistake. If Rails messed-up the way CSS files are loaded up, then it's not my mistake.

Comment: Do you want to use the Asset Pipeline? If so, you need to use embeded Ruby in your CSS files (as the file names of the assets change in production).

Comment: @nTraum "Do you want to use the Asset Pipeline?" Isn't it obvious what I am trying to do?

Comment: Did you disable the Assets Pipeline properly in `config/application.rb`? `config.assets.enabled` should be set to `false` then.

Comment: You'll need to use SCSS to & use a dynamic path-compiler such as `asset-path` or `image-path` to create the images to run at runtime. We have this working & I could publish the live code, but I think you'll just downvote it, so I sent a message to help you appreciate what the problem is

Comment: As already said, simply disable the Assets Pipeline if you want to use plain CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want Rails to touch any of the assets you can put them in the **public** directory.

That way you won't have any fingerprinting or unwanted preprocessing. They will be served "as is". You don't have to mess with the Rails settings or do any precompilation.

And if you some day choose to use the asset pipeline again you can use both methods.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use fingerprinted assets in your stylesheets and javascript files you NEED preprocessing on those assets in order to use the asset pipeline helper methods. Rather than ranting and raving try and read the ever-so-informative [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets).

You've rightly identified that your asset is compiled with a fingerprint, this is for asset expiry and is an integral part of the pipeline. In order to interpolate the correct filename to your other assets you need to use the helpers provided. For ERB use `asset_path`, and with Sass you have `image-url`/`image-path`/`asset-url`/`asset-path`/etc depending on your requirement.

Comment: I have downvoted your answer, as it was not helpful, and reported your comment. Please do try to be polite, not use offensive words, and keep some things to yourself, next time.

Comment: Your attitude in this whole question has been unsavoury, so feel free to downvote/flag this comment, too :). God help anyone who has to work with you.

Comment: I don't have any problem with people around me at work. Thanks for your concern but keep your opinions to yourself please, especially the ones that are not based on any facts.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the image helpers in your CSS for it to reference the digest version of your image?

Something like...

```
html {
  background-image: image-url('homepage_bg_1.jpg');
}
```

This will put a reference to the image with the digest string appended to the name automatically for you.

Comment: "Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped." This is what I get